# Sencha 2 List Scroll Performance

Tags: performance, list, scroll, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone have experience with scroll performance of lists in Sencha 2?

We have problems with scrolling a long list in Sencha 1.1. Even tried the community component Ext.ux.BufferedList without any success.

Is it worth switching to the new version only for this single reason? What are your experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-developer-preview/

Sencha says it is (and the video shows it too). In my experience ST2 runs smoother than ST1.1 and is better documented to boot.

Having said that, I'm not sure this is the best type of question to be asking here.